# Java Serialization issues

Tags: java, serialization

I have this code that writes an object:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Model.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
out.writeObject(this);
out.close();
fileOut.close();
```

And this code that loads the object:

```
Model m = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Model.ser");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    m = (Model) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    fileIn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}

setStudentList(m.getStudentList());
setModuleList(m.getModuleList());
```

I'm pretty sure that saving works, as when I opened the file in notepad++ I saw most of the data that I had saved, but when I load there is no data in module list.

Full source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Model implements java.io.Serializable {

private Student[] studentList = new Student[0];
private Module[] moduleList = new Module[0];

public void menu() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println ("MENU");
        System.out.println ("");
        System.out.println ("   1 - Run Tests");
        System.out.println ("   2 - Add Student");
        System.out.println ("   3 - Add Module");
        System.out.println ("   4 - Add Student To Module");
        System.out.println ("   5 - Save System (Text file)");
        System.out.println ("   6 - Load System (Text file)");
        System.out.println ("   7 - Save System (Serialized)");
        System.out.println ("   8 - Load System (Serialized)");
        System.out.println ("   9 - Print Report");
        System.out.println ("");
        System.out.print ("Enter choice: ");

        String input = keyboard.readString();

        switch (input) {
            case "1" :
                runTests();
                break;
            case "2" :
                System.out.print("First Name : ");
                String fN = keyboard.readString();
                System.out.print("Surname : ");
                String sN = keyboard.readString();
                System.out.print("Course Code : ");
                String c = keyboard.readString();
                System.out.print("User ID : ");
                String iD = keyboard.readString();
                AddStudent(iD, sN, fN, c);
                break;

            case "3" :
                System.out.print("Module Code : ");
                String code = keyboard.readString();
                String[] temp = new String[0];
                AddModule(code,temp);
                break;
            case "4" :
                System.out.print("Module Code : ");
                code = keyboard.readString();
                Module m = findAModule(code);
                if (m != null) {
                    System.out.print("User ID : ");
                    iD = keyboard.readString();
                    Student s = findAStudent(iD);
                    if (s != null) {
                        m.addThisStudent(s);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Student not found");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Module not found");
                }
                break;
            case "5" :
                saveToTextFiles();
                break;
            case "6" :
                loadFromTextFiles();
                break;
            case "7" :
                saveSerialized();
                break;
            case "8" :

                break;
            case "9" :
                printReport();
                break;                  
        }
    }
}

public void runTests() {
    loadFromTextFiles();
    saveSerialized();
    printReport();
}

public void loadFromTextFiles() {
    studentList = new Student[0];
    moduleList = new Module[0];
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("students.txt")));
        int num = fileReader.nextInt(); fileReader.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String u = fileReader.nextLine();
            String sn = fileReader.nextLine();
            String fn = fileReader.nextLine();
            String c = fileReader.nextLine();
            AddStudent(u, sn, fn, c);   
        }
        fileReader.close();

        fileReader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("modules.txt")));
        num = fileReader.nextInt(); fileReader.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String code = fileReader.nextLine();
            int numOfStudents = fileReader.nextInt(); fileReader.nextLine();
            String[] students = new String[numOfStudents];
            for (int j = 0; j < numOfStudents; j++) {
                students[j] = fileReader.nextLine();
            }
            AddModule(code, students);  
        }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

}

public void saveToTextFiles () {
    try {
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter (new FileOutputStream("students.txt")));
        outfile.println(studentList.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
            outfile.println(studentList[i].getUID());
            outfile.println(studentList[i].getSN());
            outfile.println(studentList[i].getFN());
            outfile.println(studentList[i].getDegree());
        }
        outfile.close();

        outfile = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter (new FileOutputStream("modules.txt")));
        outfile.println(moduleList.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < moduleList.length; i++) {
            outfile.println(moduleList[i].getCode());
            outfile.println(moduleList[i].getStudents().length);
            for (int j = 0; j < moduleList[i].getStudents().length; j++) {
                outfile.println(moduleList[i].getStudents()[j]);
            }
        }
        outfile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void saveSerialized() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Model.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(this);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();

        FileOutputStream fileOut2 = new FileOutputStream("Module.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut2);
        out2.writeObject(studentList);
        out2.close();
        fileOut2.close();

        FileOutputStream fileOut3 = new FileOutputStream("Student.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out3 = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut3);
        out3.writeObject(moduleList);
        out3.close();
        fileOut3.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

public void loadSerialized() {
    Model m = null;
    try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Model.ser");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         m = (Model) in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    setStudentList(m.getStudentList());
    setModuleList(m.getModuleList());
}

private Module[] getModuleList() {
    return moduleList;
}

private Student[] getStudentList() {
    return studentList;
}

private void setModuleList(Module[] m) {
    moduleList = m.clone();
}

private void setStudentList(Student[] s) {
    studentList = s.clone();
}

private void AddModule(String code, String[] students) {
    int length = moduleList.length;
    Module NewArray[] = new Module[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
        if (i < length) {
            NewArray[i] = new Module(moduleList[i]);
        }
    }
    NewArray[length] = new Module(code, students);
    moduleList = NewArray.clone();
}

private void AddStudent(String u, String sn, String fn, String c) {
    int length = studentList.length;
    Student NewArray[] = new Student[length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
        if (i < length) {
            NewArray[i] = new Student(studentList[i]);
        }
    }
    NewArray[length] = new Student(u, sn, fn, c);
    studentList = NewArray.clone();
}

public void printReport() {
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleList.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(moduleList[i].toString(this));
    }
}

public Student findAStudent(String uid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
        if (studentList[i].getUID().compareTo(uid) == 0) {
            return studentList[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Module findAModule(String code) {
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleList.length; i++) {
        if (moduleList[i].getCode().compareTo(code) == 0) {
            return moduleList[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Post complete source code of Model class.

Comment: Please explain what the 'issues' are

Comment: The issues are that if I save some data using `saveSerialized()` I cant get the data back with `loadSerialized()`

Comment: you are writing module and student list as well, so what it reads back from them?

Comment: I'm not sure why I wrote them out originally, but I assumed since model holds the arrays of Module and Student they would all be read in at once. If this isn't the case, how would I go about reading each element of the arrays in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code sample, in particular the switch statement:

```
switch (input) {

    ...

    case "8" :

        break;

    ...

}
```

I'd assume the method `loadSerialized` should be called there but it's missing and is not called anywhere else in the code.

Once you actually call the method that does the loading, the code will work, assuming you have declared a `serialVersionUID` for both `Student` and `Module`.

**Edit: why using serialization to persist objects is a bad idea**

In simple terms, using serialization to persist objects is brittle.

An object's serialized form is tied to its class.  Classes tend to change over time, meaning the serialized instance of the old cannot be loaded into the new.

While you can work round this by setting a `serialVersionUID` doing so introduces a reverse of the problem where, in the case new fields are introduced, the new cannot be read into objects of the old class, which can be a problem if you do rolling updates to the deployed system.

There's a host of other reasons - it's not easily readable (meaning you can't update it like you would a database or XML/JSON doc), it's inefficient, etc.

Comment: FWIW, the serialVersionUID isn't absolutely necessary. serialVersionUID's are like public defenders. If you don't provide one, one will be provided for you, it just may not be the one you want.

Comment: Yes, but the `serialVersionUID` that's provided can vary when the class is [re]compiled, so if you're going to use serialization to persist objects (which is a bad idea in the first place), it best to be safe and add one.

Comment: Oh wow, im not sure how I missed that, thanks! I've read allot about using serialisation for persistence, why is it a bad thing?